# Conditional Wordpress archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hopefully I can word this question in a way that makes sense.

Let's assume that I had a blog with 100 posts and that I published all these posts at the same time. Now at the bottom of each post I want to have a link to an archive page which only displays those posts that came before. So on post no 1 there would be no link but on post no 2, the link to "Previous Posts" would go to a page showing post no 1. On the bottom of post no 3, the link would go to a page showing posts no 1 and 2 and so forth.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Was just thinking that one way to do this might be to pass the post id through to the archive page as a variable and then display all posts that have a lower value than the variable. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok.. and whats your question now?

Comment: Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this.

Comment: Thank you, that's incredibly helpful

Comment: You didn't show any intention to solve your problem. Atleast you added some thoughts now. Did you think about `previous_post_link()` ?

Comment: I didnt't show intention because I'm not a programmer and didn't really have any idea except for the edit that I added before your last comment. I will have a look at previous_post_link()